# python, scikits-learn: which learning methods support sparse feature vectors?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikits, scikit-learn

I'm getting a memory error trying to do KernelPCA on a data set of 30.000 texts. RandomizedPCA works alright. I think what's happening is that RandomizedPCA works with sparse arrays and KernelPCA don't.

Does anyone have a list of learning methods that are currently implemented with sparse array support in scikits-learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have that yet. You have to read the docstrings of the individual classes for now.

Anyway, non linear models do not tend to work better than linear model for high dim sparse data such as text documents (and they can overfit more easily).

Comment: Side remark: quadratic kernels are known to work better than linear ones for some NLP tasks (though maybe not document-level work, where bigrams may be preferable).

Comment: humm! Nice to know. I was thinking about Kernel PCA because the RandomizedPCA gives a very tangled visualization for my dataset, with points concentrated along the axis. I wanted to be able to graphically visualize the clusters I obtained with other methods in a 2d plot. :(

Comment: Indeed, though Larsmans polynomial trick can be simulated more efficiently using linear models and hashed non-local co-occurrence features.